# Looking for potential problems by setting session cookie for every user

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-sessions

For the business-logic reason, I need to set a `sessionid` cookie for the each site visitor, even if there are no actual data stored for this session.

It can be possible by setting `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST` to `True` and by overriding https://github.com/django/django/blob/fc4b4fd5850989458d6e54de12a29b2e40e94ce8/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py#L153 to always return `False`.
But in that case, the session cookie will be not deleted because of https://github.com/django/django/blob/fc4b4fd5850989458d6e54de12a29b2e40e94ce8/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py#L37.

Can there be problems if cookie will remain?

Or maybe there is another way to set sessionid for every visitor?

Comment: why don't you just add some value into the session of every visitor?

Comment: @Bastian Well, this will require additional middleware or modification of an existing one, and also extra space in the session storage.

Comment: if you just need a cookie you could simply add that instead of using the session system at all? You will probably need to do that in a middleware regardless what you do. AFAIK sessions are only created when you add something to them.

Comment: @Bastian I want to use sessionid cookie as some unique identifier for the current user, and it looks fine, another cookie seems redundant for me.

Comment: another cookie would be much less overhead because it would not trigger session loading for each visitor on every request...